# Solidity: Correct way to insert, read, and delete data into smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, crud, smartcontracts, remix

**Description:**

I've created a simple smart contract where I'd enter in basic information using the `enterAutomobiles()` function. To read the data, I use `getAllAutomobiles()` function. To remove the data, I'd use the this function `removeAutomobile(uint i)`.

**Issue:**

1. When data is retrieved using the `getAllAutomobiles()` function, the resulting retrieved data is a mixture of unicode characters like the following: ``` Àà Àà à 111test123test123

*Question:* Why is the above unicode characters occurring?

[image]

*Question:* How can I present the data to appear in this format?

`[ { vinNumber: 1, miscId: "11", licenseInfo: "testtest", vehicleDescription: "testtest123" } ];`

[image]

2. When I want to remove data using the `removeAutomobile(uint index)` function, where index = 0, the data at index = 0 is deleted. However, when I invoke the `removeAutomobile(uint index)` where index = 0 again, there was no error message indicating that the index was previously removed. What can I do in this case?

```
  struct AllAutomobiles {
    uint carId;
    uint vinNumber;
    string miscId;
    string licenseInfo;
    string vehicleDescription;
  }

  AllAutomobiles [] public cars;

  uint public autoMobileCount = 0;


//Enter automobiles
function enterAutomobiles(uint vinNumber, string memory miscId, string memory licenseInfo, string memory vehicleDescription) public onlyOwner {
    cars.push(AllAutomobiles(autoMobileCount, vinNumber, miscId, licenseInfo, vehicleDescription));
    autoMobileCount++;
  }
  
  //get all automobiles
      function getAllAutomobiles() public view returns (AllAutomobiles[] memory) {
        return cars;
    }
    
    
    function removeAutomobiles(uint index) public {
        if (index >= cars.length) return revert('Automobile does not exist!');

        if (index == cars[index].carId) {
          delete cars[index];
          autoMobileCount--;
        } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your enterAutomobiles function is wrong. You have to push an "AllAtomobiles" struct in your array, not an "GiveawayWinners"! That's why the getAllAutomobiles function is returning strange characters.

And by the way, in my experience, I can only advise you to change your struct name to something more clear !

Edit: When running your new code everything seems good to me :

```
>>> contract = test.deploy({"from":accounts[0]})
Transaction sent: 0x18d498309e787b6c65bad40010461a8514a373b2361b74a952a221d201de1a60
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
  test.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 672896 (5.61%)
  test deployed at: 0x3194cBDC3dbcd3E11a07892e7bA5c3394048Cc87

>>> contract.enterAutomobiles("123", "abc", "def", "blue", {"from":accounts[0]})
Transaction sent: 0x15cb272745d39287220e9286bd2542fb1c3e654032c83323b8e918207b0c318c
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 1
  test.enterAutomobiles confirmed   Block: 2   Gas used: 151166 (1.26%)

<Transaction '0x15cb272745d39287220e9286bd2542fb1c3e654032c83323b8e918207b0c318c'>

>>> contract.getAllAutomobiles()
((0, 123, 'abc', 'def', 'blue'))
```

Comment: Hi there Sam. Thanks for writing to me. I have updated the `getAllAutomobiles` function. I'll fix up the struct to make it more readable. 
Other than that, I'm still encountering the same issue...

Comment: I've added an image above. Please take a look.

Comment: Is the problem solved ?

Comment: Hey did you found your error ?